# A variation of Hahn-Banach extension theorem

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, vector-spaces, convex-analysis

Let $\mathcal{X}$ be a real vector space, and let $v^{\prime} \in V^{\prime}$ be such that $v^{\prime} \leqslant 1$. Hahn-Banach extension theorem confirms that there exists $x^{\prime} \in \mathcal{X}^{\prime}$ such that $\left.x^{\prime}\right|_{V}=v^{\prime}$ and $x^{\prime} \leqslant 1$.

Now if we let $V$ be a vector subspace of $\mathcal{X}$ and $C$ be a convex subset of $\mathcal{X}$ such that $0 \in$ core $C$. What we want to prove is that if we have $v^{\prime} \in V^{\prime}$ be such that $\left.v^{\prime}\right|_{C} \leqslant 1$ there must exist $x^{\prime} \in \mathcal{X}^{\prime}$ such that $\left.x^{\prime}\right|_{V}=v^{\prime}$ and $\left.x^{\prime}\right|_{C} \leqslant 1$.

What I am confused is that how can we extend the result of $v'$ to something like $\left.v^{\prime}\right|_{C}$. Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is $\operatorname{core}(C)$?

Comment: @QuantumSpace $\operatorname{core}(C) := \left\{x \in C \mid(\forall u \in X)(\exists \lambda \in (0, \infty))[x, x+\lambda u] \subset C\right\}$ which can be understand as the interior of $C$.

Comment: Your version of Hahn-Banach sounds strange. What do you mean by $v'\le 1$? If you mean $v'(x)\le 1$ for all $x\in V$ then your version becomes trivial bcause, for a subspace $V$, this implies $v'=0$.

Comment: @Jochen Thanks for your comment. For $v' \leq 1$, it does mean $v' (x) \leq 1$. But I do not understand that why my version becomes trivial since I still do not know why we require $0 \in \operatorname{core}(C)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\mu_{C} : \mathcal{X} \rightarrow \,\,]-\infty,+\infty]$ be the Minkowski gauge associated with $C.$ That is
$$ (\forall x \in \mathcal{X}) ~~ \mu_C(x) = \inf \, \left\{ t \in \,\,]0,+\infty[ \, \middle| \, x \in t C \right\}. $$
First note that since $0$ (the zero vector in $\mathcal{X},$ not the scalar number) is in $\text{core} \, C,$ $0 \in C$ and $\text{cone} \, C \triangleq \bigcup_{\lambda \in \,\, ]0,+\infty[} \lambda C = \mathcal{X}.$ Additionally, one can show (which I encourage you to do)

- $C \subset \mu^{-1}_{C}(]-\infty,1])$ and therefore, $\mu_C(C) \subset \,\,]-\infty,1]$ or equivalently, $\mu_{C} \big|_{C} \leq 1$ (a consequence of $0 \in C$).
- $\{ x \in \mathcal{X} \, | \, \mu_C(x) < +\infty \} = \mathcal{X}$ (a consequence of $0 \in \text{core} \, C$).
- $\mu_{C}$ is sublinear (and therefore convex; can be shown using a direct proof).

Take $x \in V.$ Since $V \subset \mathcal{X}$ and since $\mathcal{X} = \bigcup_{\lambda \in \,\, ]0,+\infty[} \lambda C,$ $(\exists \beta \in \,\,]0,+\infty[)$ such that $x \in \beta C;$ i.e., $x = \beta z$ with $z \in C.$ Since $v^{\prime} \big|_{C} \leq 1,$
$$ \langle x, v^{\prime} \rangle = \langle \beta z, v^{\prime} \rangle = \beta \langle z, v^{\prime} \rangle \leq \beta = \mu_{C}(x). $$
This implies that $v^{\prime} \leq \mu_{C} \big|_{V}$ (since $x \in V$). In view of the Hahn-Banach theorem, there exists some $x^{\prime} \in \mathcal{X}^{\prime}$ such that $x^{\prime} \big|_{V} = v^{\prime}$ and $x^{\prime} \leq \mu_{C}.$ By the first bullet point, $\mu_{C} \big|_{C} \leq 1$ and so $x^{\prime} \big|_{C} \leq \mu_{C} \big|_{C} \leq 1.$ Q.E.D.

Comment: Thanks so much!